# Scroll bug with Scrollview and Mozilla PDF.js

Tags: c#, css, html, razor, kendo-ui

I'm developing a mobile application that contains a scrollview within a PDF document renders with PDF.js (Mozilla).

The problem is that the scrollview does not allow us to scroll down and we can only see a part of the pdf file.

Here is a sample project to show the problem : http://www.mediafire.com/?9md21u9zy56dwkd

Any idea ?
Thank's in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo ui needs ths div of the page to have its width and height set.
PDF.js does not set width and height, and I do not found how to get the width and height of the PDF.

So, from now, it does not appear to be compatible.